# Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?

Tags: exception, language-agnostic

To avoid all standard-answers I could have Googled on, I will provide an example you all can attack at will.

C# and Java (and too many others) have with plenty of types some of ‘overflow’ behaviour I don’t like at all (e.g `type.MaxValue + type.SmallestValue == type.MinValue` for example :  `int.MaxValue + 1 == int.MinValue`).

But, seen my vicious nature, I’ll add some insult to this injury by expanding this behaviour to, let’s say an Overridden `DateTime` type. (I know `DateTime` is sealed in .NET, but for the sake of this example, I’m using a pseudo language that is exactly like C#, except for the fact that DateTime isn’t sealed).

The overridden `Add` method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Increments this date with a timespan, but loops when
/// the maximum value for datetime is exceeded.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ts">The timespan to (try to) add</param>
/// <returns>The Date, incremented with the given timespan. 
/// If DateTime.MaxValue is exceeded, the sum wil 'overflow' and 
/// continue from DateTime.MinValue. 
/// </returns>
public DateTime override Add(TimeSpan ts) 
{
    try
    {                
        return base.Add(ts);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException nb)
    {
        // calculate how much the MaxValue is exceeded
        // regular program flow
        TimeSpan saldo = ts - (base.MaxValue - this);
        return DateTime.MinValue.Add(saldo)                         
    }
    catch(Exception anyOther) 
    {
        // 'real' exception handling.
    }
}
```

Of course an if could solve this just as easy, but the fact remains that I just fail to see why you couldn’t use exceptions (logically that is, I can see that when performance is an issue that in certain cases exceptions should be avoided).

I think in many cases they are more clear than if-structures and don’t break any contract the method is making.

IMHO  the “Never use them for regular program flow” reaction everybody seems to have is not that well underbuild as the strength of that reaction can justify.

Or am I mistaken?

I've read other posts, dealing with all kind of special cases, but my point is there's nothing wrong with it if you are both:

1. Clear
2. Honour the contract of your method

Shoot me.

Comment: +1 I feel the same way. Besides performance, the only good reason to avoid exceptions-for-control-flow is when caller code will be much more readable with return values.

Comment: is the: return -1 if something happened, return -2 if something else, etc... really more readable then exceptions?

Comment: It is sad that one gets negative reputation for telling the truth: That your example could not have been written with if statements. (This is not to say it is correct/complete.)

Comment: I believe you are missing an opening try{

Comment: dan, ofcourse ( know DateTime is sealed in .NET as i said)
Ingo, I never gave you - reputation

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345626/how-can-i-avoid-using-exceptions-for-flow-control

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174458/exceptions-for-flow-of-control

Comment: Often times exceptions are the path of least astonishment. If you expect something to occur most of the time, but there is a chance of failure (db is broken, internet is broken, imported file is bad format), throw an exception and handle it. The exception can be thrown up many layers and handled where it needs to be handled insetad of passing it up throw a deep library.

Comment: A great post about not doint this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Comment: I would argue, that throwing an exception might sometimes be your only option. I've for example a business component which initializes its internal state within its constructor by querying the database. There are times, when no appropriate data in the database is available. Throwing an exception within the constructor is the only way to effectively cancel the construction of the object. This is clearly stated in the contract (Javadoc in my case) of the class, so I've no problem that client code could (and should) catch that exception when creating the component and continue from there.

Comment: There are many situations where the only reasonable thing to do is **throw** an exception. That _is not_ using an exception to control program flow (you're not catching an exception). You throw because there isn't anything else to do. Since you can't trust the caller to do anything sensible, you should probably throw using a helper that also logs the exception (instrumentation).  What is the caller going to do with your exception if they catch it, anyway? _That's_ where people erroneously use exceptions to control program flow.

Comment: Since you formulated a hypothesis, the onus is on you to also cite corroborating evidence/reasons. For starters, name *one* reason why your code is superior to a much shorter, self-documenting `if` statement. You’ll find this very hard. In other words: your very premise is flawed, and the conclusions you draw from it are thus wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not feeling any onus obligation here :) (liking that word though) Allow me to rephrase : "If an exception is clear/self-documenting and hounours it's contract, is it justified to use it?" or, in the general form, "is this hypothesis correct?" .  You can argue 2 things 1. it's not a usefull question, eg: "an exception is never clear/self documenting  (mind, it's still a valid *logic* question)  2. It's a hypothesis in disguise! (and thus no question)  In the first caseI think it justifies an answer (explaining as to why), in the second case,

Comment: It's not fit for SO, you are welcome to 'vote for close' ('not a real question' used to be the perfect option, I even agree now that I know SO a bit longer that the format of this questions is certainly not ideal for SO).  Fact stays :  I wanted to know other people opinions, not to justify the hypothesis.  And I'm very glad with the repsonse I got, including yours. But this is getting too long and quite off topic, feel free to PM me for discussing  any onus or logic related matter.

Comment: You have to comment your code to describe what it's doing, instead of just coding it and let it explain itself. Your code is not clean at all.

Comment: See also the answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: it's worth noting that the article posted by Falaque as "reasons why" uses a for loop with no condition and exception instead??  try {
 for (int i = 0; /*wot no test?*/ ; i++)
  array[i]++;
 } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}.
.  It also seems the second argument is PrincipalOfLeastAstonishment, which is more applicable to method naming and intent (it's obvious that a "multiply" method that adds is a bad idea and naming it as a formal anti-pattern marginally useful).  It seems to me that if there was such a strong case against exceptions that the examples would be less trivial?

Comment: I totally support the logic and theme here.  However, I think it would be a big improvement if you removed the second generic catch.  I don't think it's required for your argument and actually shouldn't be there.  Untyped catches should be extraordinarily rare (threading maybe?) in the depths of code and should just be allowed to bubbled to unhandled exception handler for the platform (ie AppDomain.UnhandledException).  Not trying to nit-pic, but if I'm against the answers below for propagating potential bad practice, then I have to be fair here too ;).

Comment: The original meaning of this principle was not to use exceptions as an internal goto inside a method. Unfortunately everybody has forgotten the original purpose and it is now treated like the tablets of Moses. The problem with taking it as a general rule is that exceptions *are* a form of flow control, with the advantage that they can take a value with them. But like anything else if they lead to spaghetti code that could be improved by removing them, remove them. You will also see a lot of sillY claims that they shouldn't be used for end of stream, even when there is no other choice.

Answer (score 208):

Have you ever tried to debug a program raising five exceptions per second in the normal course of operation ?

I have.

The program was quite complex (it was a distributed calculation server), and a slight modification at one side of the program could easily break something in a totally different place.

I wish I could just have launched the program and wait for exceptions to occur, but there were around 200 exceptions during the start-up *in the normal course of operations*

My point : **if you use exceptions for normal situations, how do you locate unusual (ie *exception*al) situations ?**

Of course, there are other strong reasons not to use exceptions too much, especially performance-wise

Comment: if you use exceptions for normal situations, how do you locate unusual (ie exceptional situations ? --> as in the example, 
Nothing stops you from catching the normal exceptions

Comment: Example : when I debug a .net program, I launch it from visual studio and I ask VS to break on all exceptions. If you rely on exceptions as an expected behaviour, I can't do that anymore (since it would break 5times/sec), and it's far more complicated to locate the problematic part of the code.

Comment: +1 for pointing out you don't want to to create an exception haystack in which to find an actual exceptional needle.

Comment: don't get this answer at all, i think people misunderstand here 
It has nothing to do with debugging at all, but with design.  This is circular reasoning in it's pures form i'm afraid.  And your point is really besides the question like stated before

Comment: You can catch the expected exceptions for flow control AND catch the unexpected after the same try block, I don't see the problem to be honest.

Comment: @Peter :Debugging without breaking on exceptions is difficult, and catching all exceptions is painful if there are a lot of them by design. I think a design which makes debugging hard is almost partially broken (in other words, design HAS something to do with debugging, IMO)

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that most situations I want to debug don't correspond to exceptions being thrown, the answer to your question is: "by type", e.g., I'll tell my debugger to catch only AssertionError or StandardError or something that does correspond to bad things happening.  If you have trouble with that, then how do you do logging -- don't you log by level and class, precisely so you can filter on them?  Do you think that's a bad idea, too?

Comment: @Ken : let's say I rely here and there on NullReferenceException to handle my control flow. Do you advocate disabling nullref exception catching in your environment development? If you do so, what if an unexpected (ie, not used for regular control flow ) nullref exception is raised? You simply don't have any way to locate it easily (since if you catch nullref exceptions, you'll be stuck in endless loops raising nullref exceptions every few milliseconds for 'regular control flow reasons' ...

Comment: Brann: As I tried to say (but maybe wasn't very clear), type is important.  Therefore, NullReferencException is probably a bad one to use for control flow.  But that doesn't mean something like StopIteration or MildWarning would be bad.

Comment: @Ken: Unfortunately, most people relying on exceptions are re-using standard exceptions. Or, to be more specific, they let the CLR raise those exceptions (eg they don't test a variable for nullity, and handle the nullref if needed). That being said, even with user exceptions, my point still stands, unless you rely on a different exception type each time you need to raise one, which doesn't seem very convenient either ...

Comment: Anyone trying to run an ASP.NET MVC project has, yes.

Comment: I find this answer super ironic (at least in the case of .net).  The answer is that no, I have never done this because I've never needed to.  If the code in question was effectively using unhandled exceptions and the related top level exception handlers, you would have the full stack trace that occurred leading you to the exact (or near exact due to optimization) line of the fault in question.  Why do you need a debugger attached just listening for exceptions and why is it all exceptions and not just unhandled ones?  Is your logging not working/designed effectively?

Comment: Apologize for the snark, but this answer is one reason why I think the "pro-exception" camp has issue.  We're not "pro-exception", but we are "anti-return codes".  When you code for the successful cases and just let the exceptions handle the exceptional cases, you drive a "pit of success", and reduce red-herring mistakes where "if" checks were forgotten.  It is these errors where you waste time in a debugger.  I'm not saying you're suggesting return codes.  But by having argument against them, you're also not leaving an alternative and driving the code you're struggling with here.

Comment: Badly written code is badly written code. There's no need to blame that on certain legitimate idioms that may have been used badly.

Answer (score 181):

Exceptions are basically non-local `goto` statements with all the consequences of the latter. Using exceptions for flow control violates a [principle of least astonishment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment), make programs hard to read (remember that programs are written for programmers first).

Moreover, this is not what compiler vendors expect. They expect exceptions to be thrown rarely, and they usually let the `throw` code be quite inefficient. Throwing exceptions is one of the most expensive operations in .NET.

However, some languages (notably Python) use exceptions as flow-control constructs. For example, iterators raise a `StopIteration` exception if there are no further items. Even standard language constructs (such as `for`) rely on this.

Comment: hey, exceptions are not astonishing! And you kinda contradict yourself when you say "it's a bad idea" and then go on to say "but it's a good idea in python".

Comment: I'm still not convinced at all : 1) Effiency was besides the question, lots of non bacht programs couldn't care less (eg user interface) 2) Astonishing : like I said it's just astonishing cause it isn't used, but the question remains : why not use id in the first place? But, since this is the answer

Comment: If I remember correctly the iterating for statement in Java (for (foo : bar)) relies on exceptions as well to abort. There was no guarantee that hasNext() will be called and iirc it won't.

Comment: Ruby has a `raise`/`rescue` pair for exceptions, complete with stack trace and such, and it has a separate `catch`/`throw` mechanism for your everyday's non-local control flow usage (kind of a replacement for labeled breaks) where you can throw any kind of objects around (one to indicate which catch block is interested, and one to determine its return value). So, when it comes to readability - I believe you can make them expected. _Especially_ in Ruby.

Comment: +1 Actually I'm glad you pointed out the distinction between Python and C#. I don't think it's a contradiction. Python is much more dynamic and the expectation of using exceptions in this way is baked into the language. It's also part of Python's EAFP culture. I don't know which approach is conceptually purer or more self-consistent, but I do like the idea of writing code that does what others *expect* it to do, which means different styles in different languages.

Comment: One of the best reason to not do it is that, if you don't you can debug by breaking on exceptions. Also you should differentiate what catch is used, if you use a catch all, i.e. (catch(...) in C++), that means you would catch stuff like overflows, could not allocate memory and random stuff that you could not possibly resume for. If you were to define exceptions for each kind of event and throw them correctly, it is less bad but still hard to follow because you put the throw in a DIFFERENT place than the catch !!! This makes it really hard to understand if you are new to this code.

Comment: I realize it's just a *little* late for this, but Java's enhanced for loops *are* required to use `hasNext()`, and don't use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: Unlike with `goto`, of course, exceptions correctly interact with your call stack and with lexical scoping, and don't leave the stack or scopes in a mess.

Comment: Actually, most VM vendors expect exceptions, and handle them efficiently. As @LukasEder notes exceptions are entirely unlike goto in that they are structured.

Comment: I had to down-vote for the bad information in this answer. Compiler venders expect you to use a language construct as often as it is necessary or useful; that is why the construct exists. And as for *Astonishment*, it is only astonishing to beginner programmers who do not understand exceptions. Like all language features, you just need to use it properly; that goes even for `if`, `for`, functions, and other common language features.

Comment: @Aaron Exception are for _exceptional_ situations, yet there's nothing exceptional in `if`, `for` and `switch`. Moreover, they provably have overhead associated with them.

Comment: And those of you who insist on a specific style of exception usage have made your own, personal definition of "exceptional." As others have pointed out, you have rigged the conversation by unilaterally deciding what is exceptional and then insisting that exceptions only apply to those situations. Indeed, `if( ! showUI() ) exit();` can be very exceptional and can handle errors you never thought of; by your reasoning that `if` is very much exceptional. Also, long parade of `if` all over the place to check against recoverable errors instead of just catching at end *is* astonishing to maintainer.

Comment: I just don't buy that progression to the next line of code regardless of success or failure is least astonishing.  If I say "Save()" i expect that line to succeed and I don't want to wrap every single line of code in an 'if' statement otherwise.

Answer (score 39):

My rule of thumb is:

- If you can do anything to recover from an error, catch exceptions
- If the error is a very common one (eg. user tried to log in with the wrong password), use returnvalues
- If you can't do anything to recover from an error, leave it uncaught (Or catch it in your main-catcher to do some semi-graceful shutdown of the application)

The problem I see with exceptions is from a purely syntax point of view (I'm pretty sure the perfomance overhead is minimal). I don't like try-blocks all over the place.

Take this example:

```
try
{
   DoSomeMethod();  //Can throw Exception1
   DoSomeOtherMethod();  //Can throw Exception1 and Exception2
}
catch(Exception1)
{
   //Okay something messed up, but is it SomeMethod or SomeOtherMethod?
}
```

.. Another example could be when you need to assign something to a handle using a factory, and that factory could throw an exception:

```
Class1 myInstance;
try
{
   myInstance = Class1Factory.Build();
}
catch(SomeException)
{
   // Couldn't instantiate class, do something else..
}
myInstance.BestMethodEver();   // Will throw a compile-time error, saying that myInstance is uninitalized, which it potentially is.. :(
```

Soo, personally, I think you should keep exceptions for rare error-conditions (out of memory etc.) and use returnvalues (valueclasses, structs or enums) to do your error checking instead.

Hope I understood your question correct :)

Comment: re: Your second example - why not just put the call to BestMethodEver inside the try block, after Build? If Build() throws an exception, it will not be executed, and the compiler is happy.

Comment: Yup, that would probably be what you'll end up with, but consider a more complex example where the myInstance-type itself can throw exceptions.. And other isntances in the method scope can too. You'll end up with a lot of nested try/catch blocks :(

Comment: You should do Exception translation (to an Exception type appropriate to the level of abstraction) in your catch block. FYI: "Multi-catch" is supposed to be going into Java 7.

Comment: FYI: In C++, you can put multiple catches after a try to catch different exceptions.

Comment: For shrinkwrap software, you need to catch all exceptions.  At least put up a dialog box that explains that the program needs to shut down, and here's something incomprehensible you can send in a bug report.

Answer (score 27):

A first reaction to a lot of answers :

> you're writing for the programmers and the principle of least astonishment

Of course! But an if just isnot more clear all the time.

It shouldn't be *astonishing* eg : divide (1/x) catch (divisionByZero) is more clear than any if to me (at Conrad and others)  .  The fact this kind of programming isn't expected is purely conventional, and indeed, still relevant.  Maybe in my example an if would be clearer.

But DivisionByZero and FileNotFound for that matter are clearer than ifs.

Of course if it's less performant and needed a zillion time per sec, you should of course avoid it, but still i haven't read any good reason to avoid the overal design.

As far as the principle of least astonishment goes : there's a danger of circular reasoning here : suppose a whole community uses a bad design, this design will become expected! Therefore the principle cannot be a grail and should be concidered carefully.

> exceptions for normal situations, how do you locate unusual (ie exceptional) situations ?

In many reactions sth. like this shines trough. Just catch them, no? Your method should be clear, well documented, and hounouring it's contract.  I don't get that question I must admit.

Debugging on all exceptions : the same, that's just done sometimes because the design not to use exceptions is common.  My question was : why is it common in the first place?

Comment: 1) Do you always check `x` before calling `1/x`? 2) Do you wrap every division operation into a try-catch block to catch `DivideByZeroException`? 3) What logic do you put into the catch block to recover from `DivideByZeroException`?

Comment: Except DivisionByZero and FileNotFound are bad examples since they are exceptional cases that should be treated as exceptions.

Comment: There is nothing "overly exceptional" about a file-not-found in the manner than "anti-exception" people here are touting. `openConfigFile();` can be followed by a caught FileNotFound with `{ createDefaultConfigFile(); setFirstAppRun(); }` FileNotFound exception handled gracefully; no crash, let's make the end user's experience better, not worse. You may say "But what if this wasn't really the first run and they get that every time?" At least the app runs every time and not crashing every startup! On a 1-to-10 "this is terrible": "first-run" every startup = 3 or 4, *crash* every startup = 10.

Comment: Your examples are exceptions. No, you don't always check `x` before calling `1/x`, because it's usually fine. The exceptional case is the case where it isn't fine. We're not talking earth-shattering here, but for example for a basic integer given a random `x`, only 1 in 4294967296 would fail to do the division. That's exceptional and exceptions is a good way to deal with that. However, you could use exceptions to implement the equivalent of a `switch` statement, but it'd be pretty silly.

Answer (score 24):

Before exceptions, in C, there were `setjmp` and `longjmp` that could be used to accomplish a similar unrolling of the stack frame.

Then the same construct was given a name: "Exception". And most of the answers rely on the meaning of this name to argue about its usage, claiming that exceptions are intended to be used in exceptional conditions. That was never the intent in the original `longjmp`. There were just situations where you needed to break control flow across many stack frames.

Exceptions are slightly more general in that you can use them within the same stack frame too. This raises analogies with `goto` that I believe are wrong. Gotos are a tightly coupled pair (and so are `setjmp` and `longjmp`). Exceptions follow a loosely coupled publish/subscribe that is much cleaner! Therefore using them within the same stack frame is hardly the same thing as using `goto`s.

The third source of confusion relates to whether they are checked or unchecked exceptions. Of course, unchecked exceptions seem particularly awful to use for control flow and perhaps a lot of other things.

Checked exceptions however are great for control flow, once you get over all the Victorian hangups and live a little.

My favorite usage is a sequence of `throw new Success()` in a long fragment of code that tries one thing after the other until it finds what it is looking for. Each thing -- each piece of logic -- may have arbritrary nesting so `break`'s are out as also any kind of condition tests. The `if-else` pattern is brittle. If I edit out an `else` or mess up the syntax in some other way, then there is a hairy bug.

Using `throw new Success()` ***linearizes*** the code flow. I use locally defined `Success` classes -- checked of course -- so that if I forget to catch it the code won't compile. And I don't catch another method's `Success`es.

Sometimes my code checks for one thing after the other and only succeeds if everything is OK. In this case I have a similar linearization using `throw new Failure()`.

Using a separate function messes with the natural level of compartmentalization. So the `return` solution is not optimal. I prefer to have a page or two of code in one place for cognitive reasons. I don't believe in ultra-finely divided code.

What JVMs or compilers do is less relevant to me unless there is a hotspot. I cannot believe there is any fundamental reason for compilers to not detect locally thrown and caught Exceptions and simply treat them as very efficient `goto`s at the machine code level.

As far as using them across functions for control flow -- i. e. for common cases rather than exceptional ones -- I cannot see how they would be less efficient than multiple break, condition tests, returns to wade through three stack frames as opposed to just restore the stack pointer.

I personally do not use the pattern across stack frames and I can see how it would require design sophistication to do so elegantly. But used sparingly it should be fine.

Lastly, regarding surprising novice programmers, it is not a compelling reason. If you gently introduce them to the practice, they will learn to love it. I remember C++ used to surprise and scare the heck out of C programmers.

Comment: Using this pattern, most of my coarse functions have two little catches at the end -- one for Success and one for Failure and that's where the function wraps up things such as prepare the correct servlet response or prepare return values.  Having a single place to do the wrap-up is nice.  The `return`-pattern alternative would require two functions for every such function. An outer one to prepare the servlet response or other such actions, and an inner one to do the computation.  PS: An English professor would probably suggest I use "astonishing" rather than "surprising" in the last para :-)

Answer (score 14):

The standard anwser is that exceptions are not regular and should be used in exceptional cases.

One reason, which is important to me, is that when I read a `try-catch` control structure in a software I maintain or debug, I try to find out why the original coder used an exception handling instead of an `if-else` structure. And I expect to find a good answer.

Remember that you write code not only for the computer but also for other coders. There is a semantic associated to an exception handler that you cannot throw away just because the machine doesn't mind.

Comment: An underappreciated answer I think. The computer might not slow down much when it finds an exception being swallowed but when I'm working on someone else's code and I come across it it stops me dead in my tracks while I work out if I've missed something important that I didn't know, or if there's actually no justification for the use of this anti-pattern.

Answer (score 12):

Josh Bloch deals with this topic extensively in Effective Java. His suggestions are illuminating and should apply to .NET as well (except for the details).

In particular, exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances. The reasons for this are usability-related, mainly. For a given method to be maximally usable, its input and output conditions should be maximally constrained.

For example, the second method is easier to use than the first:

```
/**
 * Adds two positive numbers.
 *
 * @param addend1 greater than zero
 * @param addend2 greater than zero
 * @throws AdditionException if addend1 or addend2 is less than or equal to zero
 */
int addPositiveNumbers(int addend1, int addend2) throws AdditionException{
  if( addend1 <= 0 ){
     throw new AdditionException("addend1 is <= 0");
  }
  else if( addend2 <= 0 ){
     throw new AdditionException("addend2 is <= 0");
  }
  return addend1 + addend2;
}

/**
 * Adds two positive numbers.
 *
 * @param addend1 greater than zero
 * @param addend2 greater than zero
 */
public int addPositiveNumbers(int addend1, int addend2) {
  if( addend1 <= 0 ){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("addend1 is <= 0");
  }
  else if( addend2 <= 0 ){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("addend2 is <= 0");
  }
  return addend1 + addend2;
}
```

In either case, you need to check to make sure that the caller is using your API appropriately. But in the second case, you require it (implicitly). The soft Exceptions will still be thrown if the user didn't read the javadoc, but:

> 1. You don't need to document it.
> 2. You don't need to test for it (depending upon how aggresive your
>    unit testing strategy is).
> 3. You don't require the caller to handle three use cases.

The ground-level point is that Exceptions should *not* be used as return codes, largely because you've complicated not only YOUR API, but the caller's API as well.

Doing the right thing comes at a cost, of course. The cost is that everyone needs to understand that they need to read and follow the documentation. Hopefully that is the case anyway.

Answer (score 9):

How about performance?  While load testing a .NET web app we topped out at 100 simulated users per web server until we fixed a commonly-occuring exception and that number increased to 500 users.

Answer (score 8):

I think that you can use Exceptions for flow control. There is, however, a flipside of this technique. Creating Exceptions is a costly thing, because they have to create a stack trace. So if you want to use Exceptions more often than for just signalling an exceptional situation you have to make sure that building the stack traces doesn't negatively influence your performance.

The best way to cut down the cost of creating exceptions is to override the fillInStackTrace() method like this:

```
public Throwable fillInStackTrace() { return this; }
```

Such an exception will have no stacktraces filled in.

Comment: The stacktrace also requires the caller to "know about" (i.e. have a dependency upon) all Throwables in the stack. This is a bad thing. Throw exceptions appropriate to the level of abstraction (ServiceExceptions in Services, DaoExceptions from Dao methods, etc). Just translate if necessary.

Comment: Apart of having normal Exceptions handled with `raise` and `rescue`, the programming language Ruby has a second feature which allows you to `throw` and `catch` symbols. I think this naturally avoids the impact of creating a stack trace and just throws a little piece of text to the next catcher up the stack.

Answer (score 8):

Here are best practices I described in my [blog post](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/02/26/exceptions-for-flow-control-in-c/):

- **Throw an exception to state an unexpected situation** in your software.
- **Use return values for input validation**.
- If you know how to deal with exceptions a library throws, **catch them at the lowest level possible**.
- If you have an unexpected exception, discard current operation completely. **Don’t pretend you know how to deal with them**.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really see how you're controlling program flow in the code you cited.  You'll never see another exception besides the ArgumentOutOfRange exception.  (So your second catch clause will never be hit).  All you're doing is using an extremely costly throw to mimic an if statement.

Also you aren't performing the more sinister of operations where you just throw an exception purely for it to be caught somewhere else to perform flow control.  You're actually handling an exceptional case.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the reasons stated, one reason not to use exceptions for flow control is that it can greatly complicate the debugging process.

For example, when I'm trying to track down a bug in VS I'll typically turn on "break on all exceptions". If you're using exceptions for flow control then I'm going to be breaking in the debugger on a regular basis and will have to keep ignoring these non-exceptional exceptions until I get to the real problem. This is likely to drive someone mad!!

Comment: I already handeld that one higer : 
Debugging on all exceptions : the same, that's just done because the design not to use exceptions is common. My question was : why is it common in the first place?

Comment: So is your answer basically "It's bad because Visual Studio has this one feature..."? I have been programming for about 20 years now, and I did not even notice that there was a "break on all exceptions" option. Still, "because of this one feature!" sounds like a weak reason. Just trace the exception to its source; hopefully you are using a language that makes this easy - otherwise your problem is with the language features, not with the general usage of exceptions themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume you have a method that does some calculations. There are many input parameters  it has to validate, then to return a number greater then 0.

Using return values to signal validation error, it's simple: if method returned a number lesser then 0, an error occured. How to tell then *which* parameter didn't validate?

I remember from my C days a lot of functions returned error codes like this:

```
-1 - x lesser then MinX
-2 - x greater then MaxX
-3 - y lesser then MinY
```

etc.

Is it really less readable then throwing and catching an exception?

Comment: that's why they invented enums :)
But magical numbers is a completely different topic.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constant

Comment: Great example. I was about to write the same thing. @IsakSavo: Enums aren't helpful in this situation if the method is expected to return some meaning value or object. E.g. getAccountBalance() should return a Money object, not an AccountBalanceResultEnum object. A lot of C programs have a similar pattern where one sentinel value (0 or null) represents an error, and then you have to call another function to get a separate error code in order to determine why the error occurred. (The MySQL C API is like this.)

Answer (score 4):

Because the code is hard to read, you may have troubles debugging it, you will introduce new bugs when fixing bugs after a long time, it is more expensive in terms of resources and time, and it annoys you if you are debugging your code and the debugger halts on the occurence of every exception ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using exception handlers for control flow, you are being too general and lazy.  As someone else mentioned, you know something happened if you are handling processing in the handler, but what exactly?  Essentially you are using the exception for an else statement, if you are using it for control flow.

If you don't know what possible state could occur, then you can use an exception handler for unexpected states, for example when you have to use a third-party library, or you have to catch everything in the UI to show a nice error message and log the exception.

However, if you do know what might go wrong, and you don't put an if statement or something to check for it, then you are just being lazy.  Allowing the exception handler to be the catch-all for stuff you know could happen is lazy, and it will come back to haunt you later, because you will be trying to fix a situation in your exception handler based on a possibly false assumption.

If you put logic in your exception handler to determine what exactly happened, then you would be quite stupid for not putting that logic inside the try block.

Exception handlers are the last resort, for when you run out of ideas/ways to stop something from going wrong, or things are beyond your ability to control.  Like, the server is down and times out and you can't prevent that exception from being thrown.

Finally, having all the checks done up front shows what you know or expect will occur and makes it explicit.  Code should be clear in intent.  What would you rather read?

Comment: Not true at all : 

" Essentially you are using the exception for an else statement, if you are using it for control flow. "
 
If you use it for control flow,  you know what you catch exactly and never use a general catch, but a specific one of course!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hammer's claw to turn a screw, just like you can use exceptions for control flow. That doesn't mean it is the *intended usage* of the feature. The `if` statement expresses conditions, whose intended usage *is* controlling flow.

If you are using a feature in an unintended way while choosing to not use the feature designed for that purpose, there will be an associated cost. In this case, clarity and performance suffer for no real added value. What does using exceptions buy you over the widely-accepted `if` statement?

Said another way: just because you **can** doesn't mean you **should**.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no need for exception, after we have got `if` for normal use or use of execptions is not intended because it is not intended (circular argument)?

Comment: @Val: Exceptions are for exceptional situations - if we detect enough to throw an exception and handle it, we have enough information to *not* throw it and still handle it. We can go straight to the handling logic and skip the expensive, superfluous try/catch.

Comment: By that logic, you might as well not have exceptions and always do a system exit instead of throwing an exception. If you want to do anything before exiting, then make a wrapper and call that. Java example: `public class ExitHelper{ public static void cleanExit() { cleanup(); System.exit(1); } }` Then just call that instead of throwing: `ExitHelper.cleanExit();` If your argument were sound, then this would be the preferred approach and there would be no exceptions. You are basically saying "The only reason for exceptions is to crash in a different way."

Comment: @Aaron: If I both throw and catch the exception, I have enough information to avoid doing so. That doesn't mean that all exceptions are suddenly fatal. Other code I don't control might catch it, and that's fine. My argument, which remains sound, is that throwing and catching an exception in the same context is superfluous. I did not, nor would I, state that all exceptions should exit the process.

Comment: @BryanWatts Acknowledged. Many others *have* said that you should only be using exceptions for anything you cannot recover from, and by extension should always be crashing on exceptions. This is why it is difficult to discuss these things; there are not only 2 opinions, but many. I still disagree with you, but not strongly. There are times when throw/catch together are the most readable, maintainable, nicest looking code; usually this happens if you are already catching other exceptions so you already have try/catch and adding 1 or 2 more catches is cleaner than separate error checks by `if`.

Comment: @Aaron: I certainly won't argue there. Recovery takes many forms, and sometimes `try/catch` is just what's needed. Respect the sharp knife and it will serve you well :-)

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned numerously, [the principle of least astonishment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) will forbid that you use exceptions excessively for control flow only purposes. On the other hand, no rule is 100% correct, and there are always those cases where an exception is "just the right tool" - much like `goto` itself, by the way, which ships in the form of `break` and `continue` in languages like Java, which are often the perfect way to jump out of heavily nested loops, which aren't always avoidable.

The following blog post explains a rather complex but also rather interesting use-case for a *non-local* `ControlFlowException`:

- http://blog.jooq.org/2013/04/28/rare-uses-of-a-controlflowexception

It explains how inside of [jOOQ (a SQL abstraction library for Java)](http://www.jooq.org), such exceptions are occasionally used to abort the SQL rendering process early when some "rare" condition is met.

#### Examples of such conditions are:

- Too many bind values are encountered. Some databases do not support arbitrary numbers of bind values in their SQL statements (SQLite: 999, Ingres 10.1.0: 1024, Sybase ASE 15.5: 2000, SQL Server 2008: 2100). In those cases, jOOQ aborts the SQL rendering phase and re-renders the SQL statement with inlined bind values. Example:

  ```java
  // Pseudo-code attaching a "handler" that will
  // abort query rendering once the maximum number
  // of bind values was exceeded:
  context.attachBindValueCounter();
  String sql;
  try {

    // In most cases, this will succeed:
    sql = query.render();
  }
  catch (ReRenderWithInlinedVariables e) {
    sql = query.renderWithInlinedBindValues();
  }
  ```

  If we explicitly extracted the bind values from the query AST to count them every time, we'd waste valuable CPU cycles for those 99.9% of the queries that don't suffer from this problem.
- Some logic is available only indirectly via an API that we want to execute only "partially". The [`UpdatableRecord.store()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html) method generates an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, depending on the `Record`'s internal flags. From the "outside", we don't know what kind of logic is contained in `store()` (e.g. optimistic locking, event listener handling, etc.) so we don't want to repeat that logic when we store several records in a batch statement, where we'd like to have `store()` only generate the SQL statement, not actually execute it. Example:

  ```java
  // Pseudo-code attaching a "handler" that will
  // prevent query execution and throw exceptions
  // instead:
  context.attachQueryCollector();

  // Collect the SQL for every store operation
  for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    try {
      records[i].store();
    }

    // The attached handler will result in this
    // exception being thrown rather than actually
    // storing records to the database
    catch (QueryCollectorException e) {

      // The exception is thrown after the rendered
      // SQL statement is available
      queries.add(e.query());                
    }
  }
  ```

  If we had externalised the `store()` logic into "re-usable" API that can be customised to optionally *not* execute the SQL, we'd be looking into creating a rather hard to maintain, hardly re-usable API.

#### Conclusion

In essence, our usage of these non-local `goto`s is just along the lines of what [Mason Wheeler][5] said in his answer:

> "I just encountered a situation that I cannot deal with properly at this point, because I don't have enough context to handle it, but the routine that called me (or something further up the call stack) ought to know how to handle it."

Both usages of `ControlFlowExceptions` were rather easy to implement compared to their alternatives, allowing us to reuse a wide range of logic without refactoring it out of the relevant internals.

But the feeling of this being a bit of a surprise to future maintainers remains. The code feels rather delicate and while it was the right choice in this case, we'd always prefer not to use exceptions for *local* control flow, where it is easy to avoid using ordinary branching through `if - else`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically there is nothing wrong, per se, with handling an exception at a low level.  An exception IS a valid message that provides a lot of detail for why an operation cannot be performed. And if you can handle it, you ought to.

In general if you know there is a high probability of failure that you can check for... you should do the check... i.e. if(obj != null) obj.method()

In your case, i'm not familiar enough with the C# library to know if date time has an easy way to check whether a timestamp is out of bounds.  If it does, just call if(.isvalid(ts))
otherwise your code is basically fine.

So, basically it comes down to whichever way creates cleaner code... if the operation to guard against an expected exception is more complex than just handling the exception; than you have my permission to handle the exception instead of creating complex guards everywhere.

Comment: Add'l point: If your Exception provides failure capture information (a getter like "Param getWhatParamMessedMeUp()"), it can help the user of your API make a good decision about what to do next. Otherwise, you're just giving a name to an error state.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in having a look at Common Lisp's condition system which is a sort of generalization of exceptions done right.  Because you can unwind the stack or not in a controlled way, you get "restarts" as well, which are extremely handy.

This doesn't have anything much to do with best practices in other languages, but it shows you what can be done with some design thought in (roughly) the direction you are thinking of.

Of course there are still performance considerations if you're bouncing up and down the stack like a yo-yo, but it's a much more general idea than "oh crap, lets bail"  kind of approach that most catch/throw exception systems embody.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using Exceptions for flow-control. Exceptions are somewhat similar to continuations and in statically typed languages, Exceptions are more powerful than continuations, so, if you need continuations but your language doesn't have them, you can use Exceptions to implement them.

Well, actually, if you need continuations and your language doesn't have them, you chose the wrong language and you should rather be using a different one. But sometimes you don't have a choice: client-side web programming is *the* prime example – there's just no way to get around JavaScript.

An example: [Microsoft Volta](http://LiveLabs.Com/volta/) is a project to allow writing web applications in straight-forward .NET, and let the framework take care of figuring out which bits need to run where. One consequence of this is that Volta needs to be able to compile CIL to JavaScript, so that you can run code on the client. However, there is a problem: .NET has multithreading, JavaScript doesn't. So, Volta implements continuations in JavaScript using JavaScript Exceptions, then implements .NET Threads using those continuations. That way, Volta applications that use threads can be compiled to run in an unmodified browser – no Silverlight needed.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that there is nothing wrong with your example. On the contrary, it would be a sin to ignore the exception thrown by the called function.

In the JVM, throwing an exception is not that expensive, only creating the exception with new xyzException(...), because the latter involves a stack walk. So if you have some exceptions created in advance, you may throw them many times without costs. Of course, this way you can't pass data along with the exception, but I think that is a bad thing to do anyway.

Comment: Sorry, this is plain wrong, Brann. It depends on the condition. It's not always the case that the condition is trivial. Thus, an if statement could take hours, or days or even longer.

Comment: In the JVM, that is. Not more expensive than a return. Go figure. But the question is, what would you write in the if statement, if not the very code that is already present in the called function to tell an exceptional case from a normal one --- thus code duplication.

Comment: In this situation, I like the .net Double.TryParse approach. no code duplication, but no exceptions either.

Comment: So you advocate writing for each method xxx() (that could throw an exception) one accompagnying tryXxx() that does not, instead of try { xxx() ; } catch {}?

Comment: no, that's not what I mean. I use double.TryParse only when I think an error can occur in the normal course operations (typically, when the data I'm Parsing has been input by the user. I advocate using exceptions only for exception situations.

Comment: The sentence: "Use exceptions only for exceptional situations" is pretty brain damaged until we agree what an exveptional situation is.
So, the OO-foilk wisdom boils down to: "Use exceptions only for exceptional situations" and "An exceptional situation is one where you would throw exceptions."

Comment: Ingo : an exceptional situation is one you don't expect. ie one you haven't thought of as a programmer. So my rule is "write code that doesn't throw exceptions" :)

Comment: This is a contradiction in itself. If one doesn't expect it, why should one write an exception handler or throw exceptions in the first place?

Comment: I never write exception handlers, I always fix the problem (except when I can't do that because I don't have control over the faulting code). And I never throw exceptions, except when the code I wrote is intended for someone else to use (eg a library). No show me the contradiction ?

Comment: I agree with you to not throw exceptions wildly. But certainly, what is "exceptional" is a question of definition. That String.parseDouble throws an exception if it can't deliver a useful result, for example, is in order. What else should it do? Return NaN? What about non IEEE hardware?

Answer (score 1):

But you won't always know what happens in the Method/s that you call. You won't know exactly where the exception was thrown. Without examining the exception object in greater detail....

Answer (score 1):

There are a few general mechanisms via which a language could allow for a method to exit without returning a value and unwind to the next "catch" block:

- Have the method examine the stack frame to determine the call site, and use the metadata for the call site to find either information about a `try` block within the calling method, or the location where the calling method stored the address of its caller; in the latter situation, examine metadata for the caller's caller to determine in the same fashion as the immediate caller, repeating until one finds a `try` block or the stack is empty.  This approach adds very little overhead to the no-exception case (it does preclude some optimizations) but is expensive when an exception occurs.
- Have the method return a "hidden" flag which distinguishes a normal return from an exception, and have the caller check that flag and branch to an "exception" routine if it's set.  This routine adds 1-2 instructions to the no-exception case, but relatively little overhead when an exception occurs.
- Have the caller place exception-handling information or code at a fixed address relative to the stacked return address.  For example, with the ARM, instead of using the instruction "BL subroutine", one could use the sequence:

  ```
      adr lr,next_instr
      b subroutine
      b handle_exception
  next_instr:
  ```

To exit normally, the subroutine would simply do `bx lr` or `pop {pc}`; in case of an abnormal exit, the subroutine would either subtract 4 from LR before performing the return or use `sub lr,#4,pc` (depending upon the ARM variation, execution mode, etc.)  This approach will malfunction very badly if the caller is not designed to accommodate it.

A language or framework which uses checked exceptions might benefit from having those handled with a mechanism like #2 or #3 above, while unchecked exceptions are handled using #1.  Although the implementation of checked exceptions in Java is rather nuisancesome, they would not be a bad concept if there were a means by which a call site could say, essentially, "This method is declared as throwing XX, but I don't expect it ever to do so; if it does, rethrow as an "unchecked" exception.  In a framework where checked exceptions were handled in such fashion, they could be an effective means of flow control for things like parsing methods which in some contexts may have a high likelihood of failure, but where failure should return fundamentally different information than success.  I'm unaware of any frameworks that use such a pattern, however.  Instead, the more common pattern is to use the first approach above (minimal cost for the no-exception case, but high cost when exceptions are thrown) for all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

One aesthetic reason:

A try always comes with a catch, whereas an if doesn't have to come with an else.

```
if (PerformCheckSucceeded())
   DoSomething();
```

With try/catch, it becomes much more verbose.

```
try
{
   PerformCheckSucceeded();
   DoSomething();
}
catch
{
}
```

That's 6 lines of code too many.